# unable to use request.args in flask

Tags: flask, request, jinja2

I am working on a project using flask and I have a form in a jinja2 template where a user can enter a movie title  in order to change the old title the movie had

```html
    <h1> Select a field in the movie to update  </h1>
    <form action = "{{url_for('execute_movie_update')}}" method = "post">
       <label="update-title">Change the title</label>
       <input type = "text" id="change-title" name = "new-title" required>
       <button type = "submit">Submit changes</button> 
    </form>
```

How I get the new title  in my flask endpoint:

```
@app.route('/executemovieupdate' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def execute_movie_update():
    if 'Email' in session and 'User' in session:
        email = session['Email']
        user = session['User']
        if user == 'Admin':
            if 'Movie' in session and 'Movie_year' in session and 'Movie_plot' in session:
                movie = session['Movie']
                year = session['Movie_year']
                plot = session['Movie_plot']
                tainia = movies.find_one({'title':movie , "year":year})
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    new_title = request.args.get('new-title') #error happens here
                    new_year = request.args.get('new-year')
                    if new_title!=None:
                        print("time to update")
                        movies.update_one({"title":movie , "year":year} , {"$set":{"title":new_title}})
                        return render_template('movie-update.html' , movie = tainia) 
                    else:
                        print("no title given ")
                        return render_template('movie-update.html' , movie = tainia) 
                else:
                    return render_template('movie-update.html' , movie = tainia)        
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('admin.html'))    
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login')) 
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

The problem is that I submit the title and send it to the flask app but I cannot enter my if statement above even if the title is submitted
I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this simple task . Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code for your endpoint? Everything looks ok to me but its possible you may not be accepting post requests in your endpoint.

Comment: @dc3726 Just did . Did you see something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a form try

new_title = request.form.get('new_title')